# Reversing the array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im basic developer , just wanted to reverse my array list after posting the form , Here is my  code :-

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('WorkingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.form = {};
$scope.post = [];
$scope.submitForm = function () {
    $scope.post.text = $scope.form.text;
        if ($scope.post.text != '') {
            $scope.post.push($scope.post.text);           
            $scope.post.text = '';

        }

        $scope.remItem = function ($index) {

         $scope.post.splice($index , -1);
        }


       }
 }]);
```

My html code is :-

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app="myApp">

     <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script>
      myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
     <div ng-controller="WorkingCtrl" id="divmsg">
     <form name="myForm" ng-controller="WorkingCtrl" novalidate>
     <textarea cols="75" rows="3" placeholder="Share Your Knowledge !" ng-model="form.text"></textarea>
            <div id="row">
            <ul id="msgHolder" data-bind="foreach: posts">
                <li ng-repeat="userpost in post">
                      <p>
                        <a>
                         <b>User_name</b>
                        </a>
                      <div>
                      <span class="wordwrap">
                        {{ userpost }}
                      </span>
                      </div>
                   </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
         <input type="button" align="right" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 78px; padding-top: 0px;" id="submit" ng-click="submitForm()" class="shoutButton" value="Post">
        </form>
            </div>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Now this successfully gives me the post whatever the user submits from text box , but its going to the last of the array .

Which i want to achieve in first position  . How to achieve that ? so that whatever user post will be seen first & not in the last . Thanks in advance . 
Here is a Plunker in case if neccessary :-  http://plnkr.co/edit/pVnSgVE8pfaHK1PxgatM?p=preview

Comment: if you want to reverse an array in js use the reverse function ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse ) of the array

Comment: sorry your plunker didn't work

Comment: Use `unshift` instead of `push`: http://plnkr.co/edit/w1E3pcoWIBzHRRkib0jt?p=preview

Comment: Yeah ,, no idea why the plunker is not working ... im using same code though ..

Comment: working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pVnSgVE8pfaHK1PxgatM?p=preview

Comment: @Raulucco actually i did tried the reverse() function , but due to some reason its not working :( ..

Comment: as mentioned above, use unshift, plain javascript, has little to do with angular

Comment: @ABOS thanks for making the plunker work  :) .. now  comming to point whatever the user post's it should be visible in first position , in which current case its seen below the old post .. how to achieve that ? :)

Comment: ok @ABOS im trying :)

Comment: @CD.. &  #ABOS    unshift worked ^_^ achieved what wanted .Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead of `push`.

```
$scope.post.unshift($scope.post.text);
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/w1E3pcoWIBzHRRkib0jt?p=preview